# Group every three rows in a 2d array and sum one column

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum, grouping

I need to group 3 rows together, sum their salary values and access the month name from the next row (next calendar month).

```
$salaries =
[
    [
        'month'=>'January',
        'salary'=>200
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'Februray',
        'salary'=>300
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'March',
        'salary'=>400
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'April',
        'salary'=>500
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'May',
        'salary'=>600
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'June',
        'salary'=>700
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'July',
        'salary'=>800
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'August',
        'salary'=>900
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'September',
        'salary'=>1000
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'October',
        'salary'=>1100
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'November',
        'salary'=>130
    ],
    [
        'month'=>'December',
        'salary'=>1200
    ]
];
```

I tried [the code on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459746/sum-value-in-foreach-loop-every-3-time-looping), but I don't know how to specify the 4th month with the sum.

If possible, I want this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
[
'month'=>'April'
'sum'=900
]
    [1] => 
[
'month'=>'other month'
'sum'=1800
]
    [2] => 
[
'month'=>'other month'
'sum'=2700
]
    [3] => 
[
'month'=>'other month'
'sum'=2430
]
)
```

I tried with this code:

```php
$groupSum = []; 
foreach (array_chunk($salaries , 3) as $key => $value) { 
    $groupSum[] = array_reduce($value, function ($sum, $item) { 
        $sum += $item['salary']; return $sum; 
    }); 
}
```

And the result is :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 900
    [1] => 1800
    [2] => 2700
    [3] => 2430
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (very) basic solution (for my tests, I fix the typo on **February** month name) :

```
function getNextMonth($month) {
    $months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

    $pos = array_search($month, $months);

    if ($pos === false) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid month');
    }

    if ($pos == 11) {
        return 'January';
        // should return also year + 1
    }

    return $months[$pos+1];
}

$i = 1;
$trimestreSum = 0;
$trimestres = [];
foreach($salaries as $month) {
    $trimestreSum += $month['salary'];
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        array_push($trimestres, [
            'month' => getNextMonth($month['month']),
            'sum' => $trimestreSum,
        ]);
        $i = 0;
        $trimestreSum = 0;
    }
    $i++;

}

print_r($trimestres);
```

The result is

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month] => April
            [sum] => 900
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [month] => July
            [sum] => 1800
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [month] => October
            [sum] => 2700
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [month] => January
            [sum] => 2430
        )
)
```

The getNextMonth may be the only piece of code you need to add to your own code :)

Pretty sure that there  are shorter (and more elegant) solutions, but hope that helps anyway.

Comment: @Armage , Is it possible to list the other months, without modifying the calculation of the quarters so that we can display all the months?

Answer (score 0):

Update: [@Armage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487208/8238184) seems to do the trick, but just for fun:

```php
$result = [];

// I guess $iMax can just be 12, but I don't know
for($nextTriI = 3, $iMax = count($salaries); $nextTriI < $iMax; $nextTriI += 3) {
    $triSum = 0;

    for($m = $nextTriI - 3; $m < $nextTriI; $m++) {
        $triSum += $salaries[$m]['salary'];
    }

    $result[] = [
        'month' => $salaris[$nextTriI]['month'], 
        'sum' => $triSum
    ];
}

print_r($result);
```

Of course this assumes valid data, index based `$salaries`, etc.

---

*Old answer for posterity:*

I'm not sure this is what you want, and this isn't the best way, but maybe:

```php
$groupSum = []; 
foreach (array_chunk($salaries , 4) as $value) { 
    $groupSum[] = array_reduce(
        $value, 
        function ($total, $item) { 
            $total['sum'] += $item['salary']; 
            $total['month'] = $item['month'];
            return $total; 
        },
        ['sum' => 0]
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried to chunck by 4 like you, but is not that i nedd :
This the result
```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sum] => 1400
            [month] => April
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sum] => 3000
            [month] => August
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sum] => 3430
            [month] => December
        )

)
```

In fact, April must have the sum of (January, February and March).

Comment: @welson what you want is to sum each 3 months with the name of the next month?

Comment: @StavNov exactly

Comment: @welson can you edit the question to say it like that? "I want to sum each 3 months with the name of the next month".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$groups = [];
$fourth = $salaries[3]['month'];

foreach(array_chunk($salaries,3) as $salary) {
  $sum = 0;
  $month = 'other month';

  foreach($salary as $k => $sal) {
    $sum += $sal['salary'];
    if($fourth == $sal['month']) {
      $month = $sal['month'];
    }
  }

  $groups[] = [
    'month' => $month,
    'sum' => $sum
  ];
}
```

Result

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["month"]=>
    string(11) "other month"
    ["sum"]=>
    int(900)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["month"]=>
    string(5) "April"
    ["sum"]=>
    int(1800)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["month"]=>
    string(11) "other month"
    ["sum"]=>
    int(2700)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["month"]=>
    string(11) "other month"
    ["sum"]=>
    int(2430)
  }
}
```

Comment: A worthy attempt to reverse engineer the requested result, but notice "April" is in the second entry with sum of 1800, while in op's example output it should be the first with sum of 900 (I also guessed wrong)

Answer (score 0):

By implementing a "reference" (see `&$ref` in snippet) and pushing it into the result array to represent the "group", you can simply push subsequently encountered data into that reference instead instead of tracking that group's *actual* key/position in the result array.

To determine when a new group should start, use a modulus calculation (in other words, get the remainder after performing division) and check if that value is zero.

To get the month name that follows each third month, add 3 to the current index and add the modulus value (based on a 12 month cycle) so that the last quarter is given the first month's name.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2ZCsJ))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($salaries as $i => $row) {
    if (!($i % 3)) {
        unset($ref);
        $result[] = &$ref;
        $ref['month'] = $salaries[($i + 3) % 12]['month'];
    }
    $ref['salary'] = ($ref['salary'] ?? 0) + $row['salary'];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'April',
    'salary' => 900,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'July',
    'salary' => 1800,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'October',
    'salary' => 2700,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'January',
    'salary' => 2430,
  ),
)
```

@welson says:

> Is it possible to list the other months, without modifying the calculation of the quarters so that we can display all the months?

Yes, like this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pt97i))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($salaries as $row) {
    if (!isset($ref) || count($ref['months']) >= 3) {
        unset($ref);
        $result[] = &$ref;
    }
    $ref['months'][] = $row['month'];
    $ref['salary'] = ($ref['salary'] ?? 0) + $row['salary'];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'months' => 
    array (
      0 => 'January',
      1 => 'Februray',
      2 => 'March',
    ),
    'salary' => 900,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'months' => 
    array (
      0 => 'April',
      1 => 'May',
      2 => 'June',
    ),
    'salary' => 1800,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'months' => 
    array (
      0 => 'July',
      1 => 'August',
      2 => 'September',
    ),
    'salary' => 2700,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'months' => 
    array (
      0 => 'October',
      1 => 'November',
      2 => 'December',
    ),
    'salary' => 2430,
  ),
)
```